# Regex Notepad ++ delete all except japanese character words

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've been searching for a while now but still can't figure it out.
I found expressions like ([一-龯])|([ぁ-んァ-ン]) but have no idea how to delete all except these.

What I like to do is something like this:

```
1. おはようございます ohayou gozaimasu – Good morning!
2. こんにちは  konnichiwa – Hello / Good afternoon!
3. 久しぶり  hisashiburi – It’s been a while.
4. じゃあまた jaa mata – See you!
5. お元気で  o genki de – Take care.
6. o namae wa nan desu ka – What’s your name? お名前は何ですか？ 
7. …desu – I’m……です 
8. suki desu – I like it. 好きです 
9. If you’re not going to be waving your handkerchief in a heartfelt goodbye (where “さようなら” [sayounara] or “farewell” would be more appropriate), then じゃあまた is a great way to say “see you”! You can also use ではまた[dewa mata] which is slightly more polite. じゃあね (see ya) and じゃあまた明日ね  (jaa mata ashita ne – see you tomorrow) are also quick and friendly phrases for parting. If you’re in Osaka, then be sure to try some 大坂弁 (oosaka ben – Osaka dialect) and say, ほなね[hona ne]!
10. Example. ああ、それは、何ですか。
11. 1402  10時               
12. 1405  11時               
13  1408  12時               
14  1411  1分            
15  1414  2分            
16. 1450  3時間           
17. 1474  30時間
```

to

```
おはようございます
こんにちは
久しぶり
じゃあまた
お元気で
お名前は何ですか
です
好きです
さようなら じゃあまた ではまた じゃあね じゃあまた明日ね 大坂弁 ほなね
ああ、それは、何ですか。
10時
11時
12時
1分
2分
3時間
30時間
```

Comment: 10 and 11, etc don't look like Japanese to me! What rule do you have for keeping digits?

Comment: 10, is hiragana 11-17 are the time, minutes hours. so it would be good to keep the digit next to the japanese character.

Comment: no, 10, 11, 3, 30... here is normal digits, not Hiragana. There's no digit in Hiragana

Comment: Just for [REFERENCE](https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/%E3%81%B2%E3%82%89%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA-japanese/)

Comment: I do not understand Line 9 and 10: why are the spaces preserved? If that is a typo in the expected output in the question the solution is evident.

Comment: BTW, the second kanji in `大阪弁` is wrong.

Comment: Ok, here is what I have been thinking of: Find What - `(\d*[一-龯ぁ-んァ-ン]+)|.`, Replace with - `(?1$1:)`. If it works I will post with explanations.

Comment: Since your main question was "how to delete all text but matches", I decided to close the question. The Japanese char regex can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/ryanmcgrath/982242), just replace all `\uXXXX` with `\x{XXXX}` to be valid in Notepad++. Add `\d*` in front, wrap with a capturing group, add `|.` alternative (so, it will look like `(\d*(?:[\x{3000}-\x{303F}]|[\x{3040}-\x{309F}]|[\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}]|[\x{FF00}-\x{FFEF}]|[\x{4E00}-\x{9FAF}]|[\x{2605}-\x{2606}]|[\x{2190}-\x{2195}]|\x{203B})+)|.`) and use my replacement from the above pattern/answer. Best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> UPDATE as per the op's comment pointed out by Gurman and KenY-N:

Search By:

```
[^、-〿぀-ゟ゠-ヿ＀-￯一-龯\r\n]+(?![、-〿぀-ゟ゠-ヿ＀-￯一-龯\d])|[…“”’\"'–]
```

And  replace it by:

```
empty
```

Explanation:

1. `^` negate class which means to capture anything which is not there
   inside []
2. `[^、-〿぀-ゟ゠-ヿ＀-￯一-龯\r\n\b]` ranges that you dont want to remove which
   includes hiragana, katagana etc.
3. `\r\n` you need that to not replace newline
4. `+` indicates repeat of characters in the class
5. `(?![、-〿぀-ゟ゠-ヿ＀-￯一-龯\d])` this negative lookahead makes sure that
   any the previous capture is not followed by japanese characters and
   numbers
6. `|[…“”’–]` this will ensure that this missing punctuations are also removed.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5oCyZp/8)

Comment: This would just remove all Japanese characters, whether or not they appear with ASCII characters.

Comment: With reference to the link that I have provided, I haven't understood .. could you please elaborate

Comment: He means to say that the OP does not want to delete 10 from the words like `10時`.

Comment: Gurman now I see the comments in the OP's question. Thanks for pointing that out. But Tim didn't mean that. :) thanks anyway

Comment: [You are close](https://regex101.com/r/91regS/4), but still some punctuation problems.

Comment: @KenY-N updated that !!! yes Tim there was some chars which needed special treatment

Comment: @KenY-N updated

Comment: Why downvote I wonder !!! Reasoning would be great

Comment: Not the downvoter, but `\b` in a character class means backspace. `\b` is not a "character", you can't put it in a character class.

Comment: Thanks toto... i actually replaced space by somehow \b :|  and it worked... now I understand it work just by removing space :) ... updated

Comment: Ok, it works, I give you point.

Comment: This works for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Rax would appreciate if you accept it as answer. process : https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I have upvoted this answer as it appears to be working now.  Good on you.  For the record, I normally don't leave so many comments because it is obnoxious.

Answer (score 2):

[Based on this page](https://gist.github.com/ryanmcgrath/982242), this will find each sequence of non-Japanese characters:

```
([^　-ヿ一-龥！-￮])+
```

I've skipped the arrows, symbols and "weird asterisk thing" mentioned in the comments. Basically this will select any non-Japanese characters, including other language text. Note that Notepad++ appears not to allow the `\uxxxx` format, so the literal characters need to be typed in, or as I did, pasted from `charmap`.

If I do this:

```
\b([^　-ヿ一-龥！-￮])+\b
```

ie, match between word boundaries, it preserves 11時 and eメール as well. I'm not sure why, though...

Comment: This would simply remove all non ASCII digits, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't quite get your comment - it simply removes ASCII digits; double-width digits are preserved.

Comment: The OP wants to preserve `10時` in its entirety.  Does your answer do that?

Comment: It does now that I've investigated further.

Comment: This [doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/91regS/3), at least not in the demo, and probably not in Notepad++.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it works in Notepad++.